# Why im getting blank page on jsPdf output?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jspdf

I wanna get the content of the pdf file and see the content before i save it but when i do the `output(dataurlnewwindow)` function I am getting blank page, but the url is correct. When I copy the url and paste it in new tab my pdf content will show. I saw that people are putting the content in `iFrame` but I don't want to do that. Are there any solutions for that?

Here is my blank page with the url.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you having error 'Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL'?

If yes, it's [Google Chrome problem](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM%5B1-25%5D), you might want to do it in an iframe:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

  function openDataIframe(url) {
    var html = '<html>' +
      '<style>html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; } iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0;}  </style>' +
      '<body>' +
      '<iframe src="' + url + '"></iframe>' +
      '</body></html>';
    a = window.open()
    a.document.write(html)
  }


a = doc.output('datauristring'); 

openDataIframe(a);
```

Comment: I'm not getting any error on dataurlnewwindow. I'm getting that error on dataurlstring. And i was doing it with iFrame but then i can't save the pdf from the iFrame.